# Solve $\int{\frac{dx}{x + \sqrt{x^{2} + x + 1}}}$ using substitution

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've tried to use substitution for indefinite integral:

$$\int{\frac{dx}{x + \sqrt{x^{2} + x + 1}}}$$

using Euler substitution $t = \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x$, $x = \frac{1 - t^2}{2t - 1}$

then: $$
\begin{align}
dx =& \frac{dt}{(\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x)'} = \\
=& \frac{dt}{\frac{2x + 1 - 2\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}{2\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}} = \\
=& \frac{2\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}{2x + 1 - 2\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}dt = \\
=& \frac{2(\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x + x)}{2x + 1 - 2(\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x + x)}dt = \\
=& \frac{2(t + x)}{2x + 1 - 2(t + x)}dt = \\
=& \frac{2(t + x)}{1 - 2t}dt
\end{align}
$$

then apply to integral:

$$
\begin{align}
\int{\frac{\frac{2(t + x)}{1 - 2t}}{\frac{2 - 2t^{2}}{2t - 1} + t}dt} =& \int{\frac{\frac{2(t + x)}{(-1)(2t - 1)}}{\frac{2 - t}{2t - 1}}dt} = \\
=& \int{\frac{2t + 2x}{t - 2}dt} \\
=& \int{\frac{2t + \frac{2 - 2t^{2}}{2t - 1}}{t - 2}dt} \\
=& \int{\frac{\frac{2t^{2} - 2t + 2}{2t - 1}}{t - 2}dt} \\
=& \int{\frac{2t^{2} - 2t + 2}{2t^{2} - 5t + 2}dt}
\end{align}
$$

However when I checked with WolframAlpha I got different results for both integrals so I assume I've calculated incorrectly this substitution, but not sure where I am wrong.

- [integral calculated directly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%28dx%2F%28x%20%2B%20sqrt%28x%5E2%20%2B%20x%20%2B%201%29%29%29)
- [using substitution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%28%282t%5E2%20-%202t%20%2B%202%29dt%2F%282t%5E2%20-%205t%20%2B%202%29%29) and then [calculate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%20t%20-%201%2F2%20log%281%20-%202%20t%29%20%2B%202%20log%282%20-%20t%29%20for%20t%20%3D%20sqrt%28x%5E2%20%2B%20x%20%2B%201%29%20-%20x)

Thanks

Comment: Both antiderivatives are correct as they both differentiate to the integrand- you must remember that since you’re dealing with an indefinite integral, you can have infinitely many different antiderivatives that can vary by constants or are valid on different intervals of $x$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.